# RTL with Onsen-UI?

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm new to Onsen UI, and I'm developing an app in arabic (right to left direction).
I'm having difficulty in switching direction of some components like list items to RTL.
I tried the following css code int the `<body>` tag but didn't solve the problem

```
direction: rtl;
text-align: right;
```

here's a screenshot for example
[image: the text should be at the right most, not on the left]

HTML:

```
      <ons-list>
    <ons-list-header>فئة ما دون ال ٨ سنوات</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ١</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ٢</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ٣</ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-header>فئة ما دون ال ١٥ سنة</ons-list-header>

    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ١</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ٢</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ٣</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ٤</ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-header>فئة ما دون ال ١٨ سنة</ons-list-header>

    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ١</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">الصف ٢</ons-list-item>

  </ons-list>
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you give us an example? Where's the problem?

Comment: Have you solved it ?

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

Im sorry, i just remembered that my problems weren't the alignments, only that special characters were out of order. that was solved by an right to left mark.

### Original "Answer"

Your question only allows guessing, since we can't see any code so, i guess:

I had a similar problem working with Ionic (Angularjs + Cordova). I wanted to align Items in a Dropdown on the right side (german text) which had `.` in it. `direction: rtl` didn't help for those, so i had to explicitly mark any content i wanted to align right.

Maybe it's a similar problem (can't really read arabic, sorry) for you, so just try adding a `right-to-left-mark` to your texts and see if it works.

Right to left mark: `&rlm;` or `&#x200f;`

Example: `<p>Some text&rlm;</p>`

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

Comment: If it answers your question (and together with the edit it does) then mark it as the answer...